# Substitute all but the last occurrence using perl

Tags: regex, perl, substitution, regex-greedy

I have a string say `"a/b/c/d/e"` and I want to replace all except the last `/` to . i.e my output should be `a.b.c.d/e`.

How do I modify my substitute command `s/\//./g` to do the same? Also note the hierarchy doesn't always have  4 "`/`". It can be any number.

Answer (score 7):

Replace all `/` for which there is a `/` further down the string; thus that excludes the last `/`

```
perl -wE'$_ = q(a/b/c/d/e); s{/(?=.*?/)}{.}g; say'
```

This uses the [positive lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), `(?=...)` to assert the presence of `/` further down (after `.*?`), without consuming anything.

---

Another way is to capture with a negated character class pattern (and then put that back in the string) and use only the fixed string `/` in the lookahead

```
s{/([^/]*)(?=/)}{.$1}g;
```

The first approach above with a `/` match and a lookahead for the rest turns out to be faster.  The likely reason is the capturing in the `([^/]*)` approach  (and it has to copy that back in the string), whereby the first approach does a single character overwrite (the `.*?` doesn't backtrack).

Benchmarked: 126% faster under v5.10.1 and v5.27.2 (desktop) and 110% with v5.16.1 (new server). Tested with 4-10 char long strings for four path components.

Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for noting this and prompting for, and commenting on, the comparison.

Comment: More efficient? `s{/([^/]*)(?=/)}{.$1}g;`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both the options above seem to work. I went ahead with this one "s{/([^/]*)(?=/)}{.$1}g;" since it looks generic

Comment: @ikegami Turns out not (in my benchmark), thank you, added.  My guess for the reason: The `[^/]` one also has to copy back what it captured while the other one does a single character overwrite (and `.*?` doesn't backtrack).  I am testing more with longer strings, just in case.

Comment: @zdim, Captures add time. Didn't know if it would be more that matching against the string twice as yours does. Might also depend on the size of the string

Comment: @ikegami  Updated, with a comment and with longer path components -- it is more consistent over different perls and machines.  Thank you, this is interesting.

Comment: @Rancho  Glad it helped. I added the other way and the efficiency comparison.